# Fit this divs like in the image

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i'm trying to fit divs, like this:

[image]

I'm trying something here: https://jsfiddle.net/cjht221x/3/

But I don't know why anything is showing and I don't know how to configure #right-top, center and bottom to display like the image:

```
#right-top {
  }

#right-center {
  }

#right-bottom {
  }
```

Hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: there is no text in your jsfiddle, so what do you expect to show there...?

Comment: have a look into floats or other column ordering alternatives online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `display: flex;` for this type of thing.

Take a look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cjht221x/14

Comment: Didn't know that! You saved me, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Put some content to the elements. It works fine.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">sdfsdfsdf</div>
  <div id="center">dsfsdfsdf</div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="right-top">sdfsdfsd</div>
    <div id="right-center">sdfsdfsd</div>
    <div id="right-bottom">sdfsdfsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cjht221x/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to set html and body to full width and height:

```
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining the `#container`, consider `height: 100vh;` (Viewport Height) as units instead of (%) Percentage.